# Is there a way to stop all RestKit processing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I have a problem with switching controllers in RestKit's error callback. It causes an error:

```
*** -[RKObjectLoader onDidFailWithError]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1ddd9680
```

I'm switching in the method `- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` with this code:

```
[[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] client] requestQueue] cancelAllRequests];

scAppDelegate *appDelegate = (scAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
WelcomeController *controller = [[WelcomeController alloc] init];
[controller createWelcome];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = controller;
[appDelegate.window addSubview:[controller view]];
[appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

My problem is on the first line, because it doesn't cancel all RestKit processing. In the logs I see some ObjectMapping operations and they are causing a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)` error. I found a workaround - switch controller after a delay (using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`). But I'm looking for better solution.

The ObjectMapping operations are:

```
2012-09-26 14:50:09.408 dr[5004:907] W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:87 Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
2012-09-26 14:50:09.410 dr[5004:907] E restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:231 Encountered errors during mapping: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
2012-09-26 14:50:09.411 dr[5004:907] E restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:360 Encountered an error while attempting to map server side errors from payload: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
2012-09-26 14:50:09.419 dr[5004:907] I restkit.support:RKCache.m:189 Invalidating cache at path: /var/mobile/Applications/1B9919DC-0674-494D-9C26-F1FC1925E856/Library/Caches/RKClientRequestCache-dr.cloudapp.net/SessionStore
2012-09-26 14:50:09.422 dr[5004:907] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:123 Reachability observer initialized with IP address: 0.0.0.0.
```

I'm using the newest version of RestKit.

Comment: I have the same problem still if you have already found the solution please let me know. This crash is very unexpected and can come at any time.

Comment: Solution is manually cancel every pending request in queue before switching to another controller. But I didn't try implement it yet. I will post code, if this solution will work

Answer (score 1):

From RestKit 0.20.0:

```
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] operationQueue] cancelAllOperations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there are reason you're asking the client to cancel all operations? Normally you would ask the RKObjectManager to do the job.

```
[[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] requestQueue] cancelAllRequests];
```

Comment: if you do this and you have pending requests, then your app will crash. That is my experience with this...

Comment: because I want to call cancelAllRequests in function, which is processing and API request. So it deletes information about current request -> exception occours

Comment: Strange. Using this method for canceling a sync process with the server in my app and works perfect.

Comment: I see this behaviour only in rare occasions. When I tryied to debug it, I had to call every second X requests and I switched between controllers alltime...

Comment: Yesterday I've released the next version of my app and strange I'll can now confirm this behavior. Doesn't happen all the next but sometime I get a error regarding a released object as well.

Comment: The reason to use this can be "They give you a project and you don't know why they call a request many times in the `viewDidLoad` ... Since you didn't have time to refactor everything you cancel calls to let only the last"